# C# stored procedure error returning value

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I never worked with a stored procedure that returned a value in C#. I tried looking on the internet and I haven't found anything that helps. It probably because I really don't understand how it works.

```
STORED PROCEDURE - dbo.sp_Admin_AddNewUser

USE [NGE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Admin_AddNewUser]    Script Date: 05/19/2014 15:07:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Admin_AddNewUser]
(
    @firstname  varchar(50),
    @lastname   varchar(50),
    @middlename     varchar(50),
    @phone_office   varchar(50),
    @retval varchar(50) OUTPUT
)
 AS

INSERT INTO EDUSER
    (firstname,
    lastname,
    middlename,
    phone_office,
    synceratorInactiveFlag)
VALUES(
    rtrim(ltrim(@firstname)),
    rtrim(ltrim(@lastname)),
    rtrim(ltrim(@middlename)),
    rtrim(ltrim(@phone_office)),
    'A')

IF @@error = 0 
SELECT @retval = rtrim(ltrim(SCOPE_IDENTITY()))

--Add the user to the group
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EDGROUP WHERE [group_id] = @GroupID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [NGE].[dbo].[EDGROUPPRACTICE]
    ([group_id]
    ,[user_id])
    VALUES
     (@GroupID
     ,@retval)
END
```

Code to call the store procedure:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_Admin_AddNewUser", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstname","Test"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastname", "User"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@middlename", "M"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone_office", "(555) 555-5555"));

cmd.Parameters.Add("@retval", "");
cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tempUserID = (string)cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Value; //GET ERROR HERE
```

I get an error:

> Procedure or function expects parameter '@retval' which was not supplied

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@retval", ""); should be this cmd.Parameters.Add("@retval", SqlDbType.VarChar);

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not return value, it is just output parameter. Use

```
cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

instead of

```
cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

To have return value you must do

```
RETURN @retval
```

in your SP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the parameters this way:

```
SqlParameter firstName = cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
nikParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
//Rest of the params
//Then the output param
SqlParameter retValOutput = cmd.Parameters.Add("@retval", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
nikParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

I hope this helps ;)